# Question about propositional logic

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

I was just learning the truth table of the propositional logic . I understand the truth table for the conjunction and disjunction because they make sense in the real life. The conjunction A∧B means "A and B", and it is intuitively correct that "A and B" is true iff both A is true and B is true. The disjunction A∨B means "A or B", and it makes sense also that unless both A and B are false, A∨B is true. But for the material implication, A implies B, I can't really get the truth table. For example:

Let A be the statement that "I washed my dishes today."
Let B be the statement that "It rained yesterday."

Assumed that both statements are true, then according to the material implication, A implies B is also true, but there is no single connection between the chores and the weather. It sounds a little bit bizarre to say that "because I washed my dishes today, so it rained yesterday". That just sounds weird.

So why does the truth table of material implication be like that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's called *material implication*, not *causal implication* for that reason.

$A \to B$ is the claim that "$B$ is found to be true *whenever* $A$ is found to be true."

So the statement "I washed my dishes $\to$ It rained yesterday" is not a statement that you will somehow cause rain to have happened (retrospectively) when you wash dishes the day after.   It's the statement that you *only* wash dishes on a day after it rains.

The truth table means the statement is only *falsified* by observing a day you wash dishes when it did not rain the day before.

$$\begin{array}{l | l | l}
\text{I washed dishes today} & \text{It rained yesterday} & A\to B
\\ \hline \text{No}&\text{Yes} & \checkmark
\\ \hline \text{No}&\text{No} & \checkmark
\\ \hline \text{Yes}&\text{Yes} & \checkmark
\\ \hline \text{Yes}&\text{No} &\times
\end{array}$$

Comment: Can I interpret it this way, instead of thinking about "knowing the truth value of A and B, compute the truth value of A→B", I will think "knowing the truth value of A and 'A→B'compute the truth value of B"? For example, let A be "This triangle is the right triangle", and let B be "a^2+b^2=c^2".

Comment: Assume A is true, and from trig we know that A infer B is true also, so B must be true.

Comment: $A, A\to B \vdash B$ is the rule of inference called *modus ponens*: "If proposition $A$ is valid, and the implication $A\to B$ is justified, then we can prove proposition $B$ is valid."

Answer (score 3):

This is a very common problem for beginners. I can still recall asking my teacher about this very point when I was in high school, many years ago.

I like to use the example of the statement: "If it is raining, then it is cloudy."

It is tempting to think this suggests that cloudiness somehow *causes* rain, or that rain somehow *causes* cloudiness. Neither is the case, of course.

**EDIT:** We simply mean that, **at the moment, it is not** both raining and *not* cloudy. Looked at this way, the truth table makes perfect sense. The implication would be false only if it **is** raining and not cloudy. See my more recent blog posting on [material implication](http://www.dcproof.com/IfPigsCanFly.html). There, I develop, among other things, a rationale for the usual definition of material implication.

Using symbols:  $Raining \implies Cloudy \equiv\neg[Raining \land \neg Cloudy]$